# Why is my constraint setup unhappy about X / Height?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

[image: Current setup]

The above imageView has the following constraints :

- Height of 100
- Top Margin of 20
- Aligned Center of Superview X of value 0
- (Removed at build time, Width of 160, which I added to make it work. My whole question is about this)

Xcode says it's missing a constraint of X or Width if I don't add my width constraint.

I can understand why he wouldn't be able to display the proper width, hence maybe reducing the image view width to 0 in storyboard, like it's doing with empty labels that you fill at runtime. I would expect a yellow warning saying "width will be 0, not 160 !".

Why can't XCode figure out the X position with a "Center using Superview X" ? I do not understand what information is missing for him to display something nicely without the need to add auto-destroyed constraints like I have to do.

Comment: I have been wondering myself. I believe it's one of the things "that's just how it works". Thing with labels is, that they are never empty, even "" string is a string, so it "has" something to work with. UIImageView has nothing when image is nil. I am pretty sure everything will work if you put image in there with 0 width.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, without the width, Xcode won't know where to put the X if you only supply the center of your view.

For example, if the width of the ImageView is W and your center is 100, then the x coordinate will be 100 - W. Without the width, it can't calculate the x coordinate.

Comment: The view on which the image is centered  is my topmost view, surely it knows what its width is, and can therefore calculate its center

Comment: yes, it can find the center without the problem, when I said "view" i meant ImageView

Comment: To clarify, Xcode complains about being unable to calculate the image view's _frame_ without knowing its width. That's why setting a bogus width constraint solves the issue.